# Java funcion Math.random sin repetir valores

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo este codigo para que un programa le pida 20 numeros al usuario y de esos 20 le devuelva 10 aleatorios, al final tuve muchos problemas y termine haciendolo de esta forma:

Codigo que pide los 20 numeros:

```
int tam = 20;
    nombres= new String[tam];
    for (int i=0; i < tam; i++)
    {  
    String dato = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Ingrese 20 numeros, "+(20-i)+" restantes"); 
    nombres[i]=dato;   
    }
```

Y este es el que toma esos valores y devuelve los 10 random:

```
String listaNombre= "";

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i ++){
    int hola;
    hola = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()* nombres.length);  

    listaNombre += hola+"\n";

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Numeros ganadores!!\n\n"+listaNombre);
```

El problema es que no se como hacer que no se repitan los valores, necesito 10 distintos, si alguien me puede ayudar de alguna manera estaria muy agradecido.

Comment: Haz la comprobación "a mano". Opción A: Después de obtener el número, compruebas si ya está en los seleccionados y si es así repites la elección. Opción B: Cada vez que escoges un número, lo eliminas de los disponibles para que sea imposible volver a seleccionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de utilizar el Math.random(), utilice la clase Random con una semilla Long.

Antes del ciclo, instanciar un randomizer así:

```
java.util.Random randomizer = new java.util.Random(java.lang.System.nanoTime());
```

y dentro del ciclo for, utilizar algo como esto:

```
int n = randomizer.nextInt(nombres.length);
```

Puede obtener más información sobre la clase Random consultando la pagina de la API java.util.Random en https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Esto no garantiza que no se repitan números. Y el cambio de `Math.random()` a crear tu propia instancia de `Random()` no afecta al resultado.

Comment: La ventaja de crear la instancia de Random es que se puede controlar la semilla. Los pseudo aleatorios, con la misma semilla generan la misma secuencia y pueden realizarse pruebas con facilidad. Para el caso de que se genere un entero que ya habia sido generado con anterioridad, se soluciona con un colección en el que se agreguen los enteros generados, solo cuando no se han agregado con anterioridad. Al final, solo quedaria recuperar del arreglo inicial, los que esten en la coleccion.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolvería guardando en un Set<> los numeros que van apareciendo, y comprobar si esta en el Set.

1) Si está en el **Set** continuar sin incrementar el índice **i**.

2) Si no está en el **Set**, agregarlo al **Set** y a la **listaNombre**.

```
String listaNombre = "";
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int hola;
    hola = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres.length);
    if(set.contains(hola))
        continue;
    set.add(hola);

    listaNombre += hola + "\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Numeros ganadores!!\n\n" + listaNombre);
```