# ¿Dónde está el fallo? Array números aleatorios sin repetir en Java

Tags: java, array

No consigo ver el fallo en el código. Como pongo en el título, tengo que generar un array con números aleatorios sin que se repitan entre ellos. Se que hay varias preguntas iguales y he encontrado varias formas de hacerlo, pero me gustaría saber cuál es el fallo aquí. Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

```
    int aux;
    int [] a = new int [10];
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        a[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<a.length;){
            if (a[i]==a[j] && i!=j){
                a[j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            }else{
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for (int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
            if (a[i]>a[j]){
                aux=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema está en que no compruebas realmente si ya asignaste el número aleatorio.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea implementar un algoritmo que llene un arreglo con números enteros aleatoriamente sin que estos se repitan. El orden no importa.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para implementar el algoritmo usaremos dos bucles `while` anidados y un bucle `for`. Como variables declararemos un `array` de enteros que almacenará los números aleatorios, además usaremos una variable índice que servirá para almacenar el número propuesto en el arreglo, también usaremos una variable tipo `boolean` para determinar si el número propuesto está repetido.

El código queda así:

```
public class aleatorios {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Aqui establecemos la cantidad de elementos aleatorios que deseamos
    int cantidad = 10;
    // Esta variable se usará para llenar el arreglo en la posición correspondiente
    int index = 0;
    // Arreglo que almacenará los números aleatorios
    int [] aleatorios = new int [cantidad];
    // Nuestro primer bucle que se ejecutará hasta que hayamos llenado el arreglo
    while(index < cantidad) {
        // Variable que almacenará el número aleatorio propuesto
        int propuesto = (int)(Math.random()*cantidad);
        // Variable que indica si el número propuesto está repetido
        // asumimos que aún no está repetido y la establecemos a false
        boolean repetido = false;
        //Segundo bucle que se ejecutará siempre que el número no esté repetido
        while(!repetido) {
            // Bucle que recorre el arreglo comparando el número propuesto con
            // cada uno de los elementos del arreglo
            for(int i=0; i<index; i++) {
                //realizamos la comparación
                if(propuesto == aleatorios[i]) {
                    // si el número se repite, establecemos repetido=true
                    // y salimos del bucle for (no es necesario seguir comparando)
                    repetido = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // verificamos el estado del valor repetido. Si es false, significa
            // que hemos recorrido el array hasta la posición index sin encontrar
            // coincidencias
            if(!repetido) {
                // almacenamos el valor propuesto ya que no está repetido
                // incrementamos el índice
                aleatorios[index] = propuesto;
                index++;
            }
        }

    }
    // mostramos los valores por pantalla
    for (int i=0;i<aleatorios.length;i++){
        System.out.print(aleatorios[i]+ " ");
    }
    // Inserta un salto de linea
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**NOTA**

Como nota, es importante que entiendas que este algoritmo es nada eficiente, y se vuelve menos eficiente a medida que aumentas el número de elementos que deseas en tu arreglo, en al respuesta de @SJuan76, el con mucha razón llama a este algoritmo la forma 'tonta' de hacerlo. Es importante que tomes en cuenta que si el conjunto de números aleatorios que deseas incluir en tu arreglo es igual a la cantidad de elementos de tu arreglo, las posibilidades de quedarse en un bucle un largo rato son bastante altas, pero si el conjunto de números aleatorios es suficientemente mayor al número de elementos, el bucle funcionará sin mayores complicaciones.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchísimas gracias por contestar, es justo lo que buscaba. Había pensado hacerlo así, en mi cabeza lo veía, pero a la hora de pasarlo a código me atrancaba. Lo dicho Mauricio, muchísimas gracias por molestarte en contestar, de verdad. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo resolvería usando un conjunto "Set", para comprobar que no se repita, el código sería:

```
int aux;
int [] a = new int [10];
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

//
// Agregar números sin repetir
//
for(int i = 0; i < a.length;)
{
    int n = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    if(set.contains(n))
        continue;

    a[i++] = n;
    set.add(n);
}
//
// Ordenar números
//
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j <a.length; j++)
    {
        if(a[i] > a[j])
        {
            aux = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
//
// Imprimir
//
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, Germán. Aún no he visto los set, pero me lo apunto para echarle un ojo, muchas gracias, de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Estaría bien que explicaras con tus palabras qué esperas que haga el código; este caso es muy sencillo pero en casos más complicados si la gente no entiende lo que haces igual no tienes respuesta.

En todo caso, es un error de concepto:

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<a.length;){
        if (a[i]==a[j] && i!=j){
            a[j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        }else{
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí repasas la lista y si encuenras un duplicado le asignas un nuevo número aleatorio. Pero no compruebas que el nuevo número no esté repetido. Así que si tienes (4 números) `1, 3, 1, 2`, cambias el segundo `1` pero igual te queda `1, 3, 3, 2`.

La opción "tonta" es poner todo ese bloque en un `while` y no salir del bucle externo hasta que no haya una iteración en que no se detecten duplicados. El problema es que tienes 10 números para rellenar 10 posiciones, así que puede tardar mucho en que salga esto.

Lo más normal es comprobar que el nuevo número no esté duplicado ANTES DE ASIGNARLO al array (en el primer bucle), de esa forma las comprobaciones serán menos.

Otra opción es considerarlo, en vez de una cuestión de generar los números, como una cuestión de "desordenar" los números del 1 al 10. [Esta pregunta te puede ayudar con ese enfoque](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232538/java-funcion-math-random-sin-repetir-valores#comment432083_232538).

Comment: PD: Para cuando tengas un problema de "qué hace mi código", conviene aprender a usar el depurador del IDE que uses.

Comment: Entiendo Juan, muchas gracias por contestar. Intuía que era eso lo que pasaba, pero haciéndolo en papel para comprobarlo me terminaba liando y creía que sí comprobaba que al cambiar uno este no se repitiese, pero ya veo que no. Muchísimas gracias Juan. Con lo del depurador estoy en ello, pero se me hace bastante lioso en NetBeans.